# What does the "exit status code 137" mean in laravel-snappy?

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, yajra-datatable, laravel-snappy

I'm getting the following error as a response while I'm trying to generate PDF from **yajra/laravel-datatables** using **barryvdh/laravel-snappy**:

> The exit status code '137' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading
> pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [==============================> ]
> 50% [==============================> ] 50% Killed " stdout: ""
> command:
> /var/www/html/infyom-panel/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
> --lowquality --margin-bottom '10mm' --margin-left '0' --margin-right '0' --margin-top '10mm' --orientation 'landscape' --no-outline
> '/tmp/knp_snappy5f7a1ec10b8226.89254541.html'
> '/tmp/knp_snappy5f7a1ec10f4631.61077212.pdf'.

I think that the process is taking so long, that Ubuntu is killing it off. If it's true, then is there any way to whitelist it from being killed? If not, then how could it be resolved?

Comment: Exit status 137 probably means that it was killed by SIGKILL.

Comment: @user877329 do you know how to stop SIGKILL from killing the process?

Comment: Make sure SIGKILL isn't sent to it. You cannot catch this particular signal.